# How to return multiple types of class types from single generic class in dart flutter?

Tags: class, flutter, dart, return

I have multiple class like this:-

```
Class A {
  static int xyz = 10;
  int c;
  int d;
  static A getData() {
   // Do something
    return A()..c = xyz*5;
  }

Class B {
  static int abc = 10;
  int c;
  static B getData() {
   // Do something
    return B()..c = xyz*5;
  }
```

So, here you can see that the the `getData()` is doing the same thing, but have different return types.
Is there any way to avoid duplicate implementation like this,  can it be done by defining a single function which can reference the class and have multiple return type?

Comment: You can't dynamically create an object of the generic type in Dart without using `dart:mirrors`, and Flutter explicitly removes support for that. The assignment can be done by either using inheritance and a generic type constraint or by using `dynamic`, but the construction you will have to do separately (either by passing in the already-constructed object or by passing in a factory method).

Comment: Could you give an example using inheritance or mirror?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has two parts: creating the object, and assigning to a field of the object.

Creating the object, you are mostly out of luck. The only way to create an object of a specific type in a generic method is by using reflection via `dart:mirrors`. However, you have indicated that this is for a Flutter project, and Flutter doesn't support reflection, so that isn't an option. The only way you are going to be able to dynamically create an object is to pass in a factory method that the generic method can call to construct the object.

Assigning to a field of the object is easier, but it requires that you either lose static type checking by using `dynamic` or by tying your classes together with inheritance. The latter is the preferable choice, but if you are working with a library than it isn't always an option.

Combining these two things, the code will look like this:

```dart
class Foo {
  static int xyz = 10;
  int c;
}

class A extends Foo {
  int d;
  
  static A getData() {
    return modifyObject(() => A());
  }
}

class B extends Foo {
  static B getData() {
    return modifyObject(() => B());
  }
}

T modifyObject<T extends Foo>(T create()) {
  return create()..c = Foo.xyz * 5;
}
```

Before doing this, though, I'd take a look at whether your project actually needs it. If your use case is as simple as your example, I would argue that this level of generalization is overkill and you are hurting your code's readability more than you are helping its modularity.

Comment: I would have 10 of the class like this, then maybe I will use this, thanks